# clearInteval is not working in timer with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, timer, components, lifecycle

I set up a simple timer, count reduce 1 every 1 sec and will eventually stop reducing once count reached zero, currently timer works fine but will keep reducing after reached zero. can someone tell me whats the problem?

also I am not sure if I use `componentWillUnmount()` lifecycle right.

code is below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Timer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 10
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return <h1>Count:{count} </h1>;
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.myTimer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        count: this.state.count - 1
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.state.count === 0) {
      clearInterval(this.myTimer);
    }
  }
}

export default Timer;
```

Comment: you are not using componentWillUnmount right. Your component doesn't get unmount until you leave the page. To stop the timer, just put in an if statement before the setState. if (this.state.count > 0)

Answer (score 0):

First you use setState function with prevState because you calculate the next state from current one so you should change that part.

And you should stop timer by yourself because the component unmounts when you close the page, so you should update setState method like this

```
this.myTimer = setInterval(() => {
  if (this.state.count > 0) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      count: prevState.count - 1
    }));
  }
}, 1000);
```

and `componentWillUnmount` method

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  if (this.myTimer) {
    clearInterval(this.myTimer);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.